# Prestashop product_attribute quantity

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

while adding a product with attributes and combinations I ran into the quantity column in the product_attribute table (PS 1.6),

since from what I see the quantity of combanitions is stored in to the stock_available table,

what does the quantity field of product_attribute table refer to?

Answer (score 1):

*Attribute::getAttributeQty($id_product)* returns the quantity in 'ps_product_attribute' table, and as this method's doc suggests this method is **deprecated since 1.5.0, use StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct()**. So I think this column is not used anywhere since it has been replaced by the method we mentioned above.

Comment: Some relevant `DEPRECATED` statements in `classes/Product.php` seem to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

The quantity field of product_attribute table is the minimun quantity that must be buyed for the related product.
As you can see from the admin panel 1 is the default value.

Comment: This answer is either obsolete or wrong.  There is now both a `minimal_quantity` column **and** the `quantity` column, which is set to 300 for most examples.